# Run Sublime Text 3 and check version

Tags: command-line, sublime-text

I have installed Sublime Text 3 following [the tutorial on unixmen.com](http://www.unixmen.com/install-sublime-text-3-ubuntu-13-04-13-10/). How to run it from terminal and how to check the version (from terminal or however)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The command to start Sublime Text:

```
subl
```

The command to see its version:

```
subl --version
```

Comment: And after Sublime Text 3 goes from beta do I have to do something to have stable version or? And how to update when new build is released (from terminal or from gui, doesn't matter)?

Comment: You added the ppa to your sources, so any new update should came automatically.

Answer (score 2):

The usual command for Sublime Text is `subl`:

From `subl --help`:

```
$ subl --help
Sublime Text build 3065

Usage: sublime_text [arguments] [files]         edit the given files
   or: sublime_text [arguments] [directories]   open the given directories

Arguments:
  --project <project>: Load the given project
  --command <command>: Run the given command
  -n or --new-window:  Open a new window
  -a or --add:         Add folders to the current window
  -w or --wait:        Wait for the files to be closed before returning
  -b or --background:  Don't activate the application
  -h or --help:        Show help (this message) and exit
  -v or --version:     Show version and exit

Filenames may be given a :line or :line:column suffix to open at a specific
location.
```

Hence, to get the version:

```
$ subl -v
Sublime Text Build 3065
```

[As Glutanimate noted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/524812/run-sublime-text-3-and-check-version/524816?noredirect=1#comment714531_524816), you can get the version from the Help menu, from `About Sublime Text`:

[image]

Comment: You can also check the version via the UI: *Help* -> *About Sublime Text*

Comment: @Glutanimate thanks. To discover that, I'd have to run it first. :D I'll update the answer.

Comment: I saw `Build 3065` in the screenshot and cannot even figure out it is sublime 2 or sublime 3...

Comment: @B.Mr.W. Same here. I'm guessing 3000–3999 represents version 3, but if so it would be nice to see that actually stated somewhere, especially since builds are usually given sequentially increasing system-generated numbers.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Sublime Text Unofficial Documentation:](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/getting_started/install.html#linux)

You can create a symbolic lynk `sudo ln -s /opt/Sublime\ Text\ 3/sublime_text /usr/bin/sublime`. "/opt" being the dir where you installed Sublime.

The Documentation also shows how to add Sublime to the Unity Launcher if you wish.